# How would I get values from 2 rows into one

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to access data from 2 different rows returned in the same array

Here is a picture 
[image]

I need to access first_name and last_name

Here is my script

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include_once('db.php'); // database class
$dbase['host'] = 'asdf';
$dbase['user'] = 'asdf';
$dbase['pass'] = 'asdf';
$dbase['name'] = 'asdf';
$db = new DB($dbase);

// SELECT `meta_value` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key`='password'

$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key`='user_email'");
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    echo $row['meta_value'];
}
?>
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: `meta_key` can't be `user_email` it's used for `first_name` and `last_name`,  You need to figure out how to join both those rows (what is in common with them both, if they are all different nothing in common no way to relate them together)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query..

```
SELECT 
wp1.meta_value AS first_name, 
wp2.meta_value AS last_name
FROM 
wp_usermeta wp1
INNER JOIN
wp_usermeta wp2
ON ( wp1.user_id = wp2.user_id )
WHERE 1
AND wp1.meta_key = "first_name"
AND wp2.meta_key = "last_name";
GROUP BY wp1.user_id;
```

Comment: I don't know if I am implementing this right, but here is my script https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8268156

Comment: yes.. its correct.. run it, and you will get the desired result.. :)

Comment: I want it to run through the entire table it only shows the first row

Answer (score 0):

You're already looping over these rows, just inspect the meta_key.

```
$fname="";
$lname="";

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{
  if ($row['meta_key'] == "first_name")
  {
   $fname = $row['meta_value'];
  }
  else if ($row['meta_key'] == "last_name")
  {
    $lname = $row['meta_value'];
  }
}

echo $fname . " " . $lname;
```

lastly, your sql is incorrect:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'user_email' AND `meta_value` = "$user_email_passed_in")
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the MySQL query that you're doing is wrong.

It might be

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE (`meta_key`='first_name' OR `meta_key`='last_name')");
```

In this case all rows matching 'first_name' OR 'last_name' in 'meta_key' field will be returned.

I think you'll have to distinguish these fields using also `user_id` field as discriminant.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you! This works, is there a way that I could format the output like "lastname:firstname"?