# Select row(s) using join then update mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Ok basically I need to select the submitted_link row in image 1 based on the tab_id from image  1 and id from image 2 (the join). After this is selected I need to update the tab_content row in image 2 for each of the id's in image 2. Below the images is what I have code wise right now.

Image 1:

[Database Help http://bekustom.com/Untitled-1.jpg](http://bekustom.com/Untitled-1.jpg)

Image 2:

[Database Help http://bekustom.com/Untitled-2.jpg](http://bekustom.com/Untitled-2.jpg)

My Code:

```
$sql = ("SELECT submitted_links.submitted_link, submitted_links.tab_id, users_tabs.id FROM users_tabs, submitted_links WHERE submitted_links.tab_id=users_tabs.id AND submitted_links.user_id=users_tabs.user_id");

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
$rows[] = $row;
}

foreach($rows as $row) {
$tab_content[] = $row['submitted_link'];
$tab_id = $row['tab_id'];

$tab_implode = implode(",", $tab_content);
$sql2 = ("UPDATE users_tabs SET tab_content='".$tab_implode."' WHERE id='".$tab_id."'");
$result2 = $db->query($sql2);
}
```

What I'm getting in tab_content currently:

```
ID 17: http://google.com,http://twitter.com,http://google2.com
ID 18: http://google.com,http://twitter.com
```

Desired data in tab_content:

```
ID 17: http://google.com,http://google2.com
ID 18: http://twitter.com
```

Comment: what your are getting? update is not working?

Comment: Can be more clear regarding the final state of database that you want?

Comment: why can't move your update query inside the while loop?

Comment: The update works but does not give me the desired data into the tab_content column for each id in image 2. The tab_content column should read `http://google.com,http://google2.com` for id 17, and `http://twitter.com` for id 18 in image 2.

Comment: Updated question to show current results in tab_content vs desired results in tab_content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your PHP code!

Try this...

```
$sql = "SELECT 
submitted_links.submitted_link, 
submitted_links.tab_id, 
users_tabs.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT( submitted_link ) AS all_links 
FROM 
users_tabs, submitted_links 
WHERE 
submitted_links.tab_id = users_tabs.id 
AND submitted_links.user_id=users_tabs.user_id 
GROUP BY submitted_links.tab_id";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
{
    $sql2 = "UPDATE 
             users_tabs 
             SET 
             tab_content='" . $row['all_links'] . "' 
             WHERE id='" . $row["tab_id"] . "'";

    $result2 = $db->query($sql2);
}
```

Comment: No errors being reported but it's not updating the tab_content column.

Comment: It looks correct to me logically... try to debug and see where the problem is!

Comment: Check what is the output of the first query.. After that check `echo $sql2` in the loop!!

Comment: This worked after I tracked down the issue which was just a typo:

Was:
`GROUP_CONCAT( submitted_links ) AS all_links`

Should be:
`GROUP_CONCAT( submitted_link ) AS all_links`

Comment: Ohh!! Ok.. I have updated the answer to reflect the same.! :)

Comment: Someone else also told me the same thing.. hahaha.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933812/how-would-i-get-values-from-2-rows-into-one/20933992?noredirect=1#comment31435226_20933992 Glad to help!

Comment: I got another quick question @Manu I'm trying to use the following inside the while loop after the update in your code above but it only returns the last item after the last comma when I explode it instead of listing them all from the tab_content column. Any ideas?

`foreach(explode(',', $row9['all_links']) as $split_links) {
$fix_links = '<a href="'.$split_links.'" target="_blank">'.$split_links.'</a><br />';
}`

Comment: Nevermind @Manu I got it here's the code:

`$fix_links = '';
foreach(explode(',', $row9['all_links']) as $split_links) {
$split_links = trim($split_links);
$fix_links .= '<a href="'.$split_links.'" target="_blank">'.$split_links.'</a><br />';
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query in your mysql environment. If it is worked, then no need of `while` , `foreach` loops

```
UPDATE users_tabs  AS c   
    join (SELECT o.tab_id, GROUP_CONCAT(o.submitted_links SEPARATOR ',' ) as  'links'  
     FROM submitted_links AS o  GROUP BY o.tab_id) as mysub_tab
    on c.id= mysub_tab.tab_id
      SET c.tab_content = mysub_tab.links
```

Comment: MySQL gave this error: You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

Comment: This look like oracle syntax to update select. Try inner join as shown on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247982/update-multiple-rows-using-select-statement

Comment: @kumar_v also generated an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT o.tab_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.submitted_links SEPARATOR ',' ) as 'li' at line 2

Comment: @BeKustom Updated my answer again. I couldn't test due to some problem in my system.

Comment: @kumar_v Another error: #1054 - Unknown column 'o.tab_id' in 'field list'

Comment: @kumar_v Nope: #1054 - Unknown column 'o.submitted_links' in 'field list' It's all good manu's solution worked for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BeKustom I tried to give best solution without using loop. But you are not trying from your side. his solution is working in my side. but not in your side means, you need to adjust fields name.. etc..

Comment: @kumar_v Oh I tried believe me for the past 6 hours I have tried. His solution works now that I found the typo in the GROUP_CONCAT and it has since been corrected in the given solution by manu so of course it works. Have a good day bud.